# Find Duplicates on Multiple Criteria

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-sheets

I have a set of financial transactions with a *Date*, *Amount*, *Description* and *Source* and I want to find transactions where the amount is the same, the date is within one day, but the sources are different. The source should be different because the transactions are an import from many sources and each source has unique entries.

For example, I would want to find that row 1 and 3 are duplicates:

```
'date','amount','description','source'
1/5/2018, 5.28, 'McDonalds', 'BankOfAmerica'
1/6/2018, 8.44, 'Starbucks', 'BankOfAmerica'
1/5/2018, 5.28, 'McDonalds Rest', 'BoA'
2/10/2018, 22.72, 'Chipolte', 'Chase'
3/10/2018, 4.58, 'Wendys', 'BoA'
```

I tried in Python and I can find duplicates with:

```
df_no_dups = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['amount','dates'])
df_dups = df[~df.isin(df_no_dups)].dropna()
```

but this is an exact date match and then I have to run another script to make sure the sources were different.

I also tried to *groupby* amounts and then iterate inside those to find where dates are close and sources are different, but I couldn't figure out the details of groups.

Other approaches could be with SQL or in the spreadsheet (google) where the transactions are.

Comment: can you make a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) example please, so we can replicate the question. Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 does that help?

Comment: yes, thank you, here the source column is the 3rd or 4th?

Comment: @anky_91 -- fourth -- I'll add headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use exists

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
where exists( select 1 from table_name t2 
             where t2.date=t1.date and t2.amount=t1.amount and t1.source<>t2.source)
```

Comment: wow -- this is pretty strait forward -- thanks -- and I could use a datediff function or something on that first = if I wanted dates to differ by a day

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following data(added a row in row 3 for better understanding)

```
data = pd.compat.StringIO("""5 Jan, 5.28, 'McDonalds', 'BankOfAmerica'
6 Jan, 8.44, 'Starbucks', 'BankOfAmerica'
5 Jan, 5.28, 'McDonalds Rest', 'BoA'
5 Jan, 5.28, 'McDonalds Rest', 'BankOfAmerica'
10 Feb, 22.72, 'Chipolte', 'Chase'""")
df = pd.read_csv(data,header=None)
df.columns=['Date','Amount','Dscription','Source']
print(df)

 Date  Amount         Dscription            Source
0   5 Jan    5.28        'McDonalds'   'BankOfAmerica'
1   6 Jan    8.44        'Starbucks'   'BankOfAmerica'
2   5 Jan    5.28   'McDonalds Rest'             'BoA'
3   5 Jan    5.28   'McDonalds Rest'   'BankOfAmerica'
4  10 Feb   22.72         'Chipolte'           'Chase'
```

For duplicates and different sources:

```
df_dups =df[df.duplicated(['Date','Amount'],keep=False)]
df_dups =df_dups.drop_duplicates(['Date','Amount','Source'],keep=False)
print(df_dups)


    Date  Amount         Dscription            Source
0  5 Jan    5.28        'McDonalds'   'BankOfAmerica'
2  5 Jan    5.28   'McDonalds Rest'             'BoA'
```

---

For no dups( pulling all the other rows basically `df`-`df_dup`):

```
no_dups=df.loc[~df.index.isin(df_dups.index)]
print(no_dups)

     Date    Amount      Dscription            Source
1   6 Jan    8.44        'Starbucks'   'BankOfAmerica'
3   5 Jan    5.28   'McDonalds Rest'   'BankOfAmerica'
4  10 Feb   22.72         'Chipolte'           'Chase'
```

Comment: any idea about if dates differ by a day?

Comment: I mean if the date is 5-Jan and 6-Jan but the sources are different and the amounts are the same, then it is still a duplicate because the financial records are sometime off by a day.

Comment: wait! this doesn't work. the second step just removes all those with duplicate sources.

Comment: @bonhoffer my bad, missed to insert date while dropping dups: use `df_dups =df_dups.drop_duplicates(['Date','Source'])` edited the answer

Comment: So the approach is going to remove lots of duplicates just because they share a common source.